# Summation to Vectors

Tags: summation, vectors

Say I have the summations,

$\epsilon\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\alpha^{+(i)} + \alpha^{-(i)})$, where $\epsilon$ is a constant

and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}y^i(\alpha^{+(i)} - \alpha^{-(i)})$

I know that I can change $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\alpha^{+(i)} + \alpha^{-(i)})$ into
\begin{equation} 
\epsilon
\begin{bmatrix}
\textbf{1}\\ \textbf{1}
\end{bmatrix}^T
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha^+\\ \alpha^-
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation} where $\textbf{1}$ is a (n x 1) vector.

Similarly, (Correct me if im wrong here) for $\sum_{i=1}^{n}y^i(\alpha^{+(i)} - \alpha^{-(i)})$ I would get,

\begin{equation} 
\begin{bmatrix}
\textbf{y}\\ \textbf{-y}
\end{bmatrix}^T
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha^+\\ \alpha^-
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
So if I performed the operation $\epsilon\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\alpha^{+(i)} + \alpha^{-(i)}) - \sum_{i=1}^{n}y^i(\alpha^{+(i)} - \alpha^{-(i)})$ This would give me,

\begin{equation} 
\epsilon
\begin{bmatrix}
\textbf{1}\\ \textbf{1}
\end{bmatrix}^T
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha^+\\ \alpha^-
\end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix}
\textbf{y}\\ \textbf{-y}
\end{bmatrix}^T
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha^+\\ \alpha^-
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation} and to further simplify I would get,

\begin{equation} 
\begin{bmatrix}
\epsilon - \textbf{y} \\ \epsilon + \textbf{y}
\end{bmatrix}^T
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha^+\\ \alpha^-
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Can anyone please verify whether what i'm doing is correct. If there is a mistake please explain where, why and how I can fix it. Thank you